# Strings not showing up in resource chooser

Tags: android, android-resources

Hi, I'm also doing the same tutorial

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#first_uiproperties.

I've managed to add strings to my `strings.xml` and it shows up calculate but when I go to resource chooser and try to add it to the button its not there. So what I did was create another string called `time` and then went back into my graphical layout and try to add it to a button and that doesn't show up. I've saved the project but that doesnt help I've also tried adding several strings but none of them show up in my resources chooser.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">TestApp</string>
  <string name="fahrenheit">to Fahrenheit</string>
  <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
  <color name="myColor">#F5F5F5</color>
  <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
  <string name="celsius">to Celsius</string>
  <string name="calculate">to Calculate</string>  
</resources>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the <color> element?
Either that or cleaning the project and building it again.

Comment: Check that you've imported your own R.java file and not something like android.R. Sometimes Eclipse automatically imports the wrong R.java

Comment: Try to clean and rebuilt the project. Sometime Eclispe looses resources... And yes, <color> should not be there...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the colour

check if u have imported `android.R` if u have imported in the change the import to your R file.

clean the project.

Comment: Thankyou everyone for your prompt answers but i dont know what happened but for some reason it now shows up in my resource chooser. I am following the tutorial word for word but some tutorial are not explained. I have searching for decent tutorials for a long time now and this seems to be the best one on eclipse juno. i have used abndroid for dummies, lynda.com and several you tube videos plus many more. does any know if there are some really good tutorials out there for the eclipse juno. Thankyou.